# Trying to use datetimepicker with bootstrap, not working. Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function

Tags: jquery

I looked at the answers to the other questions and tried various solutions but nothing worked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Call Report Generator</title>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

    <div class="heading">
        <h1 align="center">Call Report Generator </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="pull-left">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="pull-right">
                <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- If Needed Left and Right Padding in 'md' and 'lg' screen means use container class -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <a href="#">Start Date</a>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class='col-sm-4'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <a href="#">End Date</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <a href="#">Provider</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>

</html>
```

I tried to look at other solution for the this question stated earlier and tried different solutions but nothing worked.

Comment: You could add which questions you have looked at and which solutions you have tried :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you included the Javascript file for the "datetimepicker" plugin?. Please be sure that you include the "datetimepicker" file javascript tag before the code where you are trying to use the "datetimepicker" function.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to include the bootstrap-datetimepicker javascript as well:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```